# Error Reading from Database ... invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, moodle

I have a Moodle plugin that is giving me some issues. It works on a server with MySQL, but not MSSQL. When I try to run it I get the following error...

```
Debug info: SQLState: 42000<br>
Error Code: 8120<br>
Message: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Column 'mdl_course.category' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.<br>

SELECT c.*
FROM mdl_course c, mdl_enrol e
WHERE e.courseid = c.id
AND enrol = 'elediamultikeys'
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY c.shortname ASC
[array (
)]
Error code: dmlreadexception
Stack trace:

    line 443 of \lib\dml\moodle_database.php: dml_read_exception thrown
    line 250 of \lib\dml\sqlsrv_native_moodle_database.php: call to moodle_database->query_end()
    line 357 of \lib\dml\sqlsrv_native_moodle_database.php: call to sqlsrv_native_moodle_database->query_end()
    line 785 of \lib\dml\sqlsrv_native_moodle_database.php: call to sqlsrv_native_moodle_database->do_query()
    line 833 of \lib\dml\sqlsrv_native_moodle_database.php: call to sqlsrv_native_moodle_database->get_recordset_sql()
    line 50 of \blocks\eledia_multikeys\generate_keys.php: call to sqlsrv_native_moodle_database->get_records_sql()
```

Below is what the actual codes looks like in the plugin's php file. Is there something I can change to make this work? Thank you!

```
// Get all courses which have an elediamultikeys enrol instance.
$sql = "SELECT c.*
    FROM {course} c, {enrol} e
    WHERE e.courseid = c.id
    AND enrol = 'elediamultikeys'
    GROUP BY c.id
    ORDER BY c.shortname ASC";
$courses = $DB->get_records_sql($sql);
```

After editing sql it blows up with the following...

```
Debug info: SQLState: 42000<br>
Error Code: 156<br>
Message: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.<br>

INSERT INTO mdl_block_eledia_multikeys (course,code,user,mailedto,timecreated) VALUES('2',N'4ajenabudE',NULL,N'email@gmail.com','1406479511')
[array (
0 => '2',
1 => '4ajenabudE',
2 => NULL,
3 => 'email@gmail.com',
4 => 1406479511,
)]
Error code: dmlwriteexception
Stack trace:

    line 446 of \lib\dml\moodle_database.php: dml_write_exception thrown
    line 250 of \lib\dml\sqlsrv_native_moodle_database.php: call to moodle_database->query_end()
    line 357 of \lib\dml\sqlsrv_native_moodle_database.php: call to sqlsrv_native_moodle_database->query_end()
    line 919 of \lib\dml\sqlsrv_native_moodle_database.php: call to sqlsrv_native_moodle_database->do_query()
    line 1000 of \lib\dml\sqlsrv_native_moodle_database.php: call to sqlsrv_native_moodle_database->insert_record_raw()
    line 151 of \blocks\eledia_multikeys\locallib.php: call to sqlsrv_native_moodle_database->insert_record()
    line 75 of \blocks\eledia_multikeys\generate_keys.php: call to eledia_multikeys_service->create_keylist()
```

This is the code located by line 151

```
    $newkeys[] = $newkey;
    $newkeyobj = new stdClass();
    $newkeyobj->course = $courseid;
    $newkeyobj->code = $newkey;
    $newkeyobj->user = null;
    $newkeyobj->mailedto = $mail;
    $newkeyobj->timecreated = time();
    $DB->insert_record('block_eledia_multikeys', $newkeyobj);
}
```

Comment: Why are you grouping by c.id when you are not aggregating on anything?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did not write the original query, is there a better way to do it? I'm not very familiar with sql.

Comment: Just remove the clause "GROUP BY c.id".  The clause is used to group records and find out aggregate values such as count of records in the group, sum of values of a column in each group, average of values of a column for each group, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting that error is because you only use GROUP BY in conjunction with aggregate functions.

If you were to change it to:

```
// Get all courses which have an elediamultikeys enrol instance.
$sql = "SELECT c.*
    FROM {course} c
     join {enrol} e
       on e.courseid = c.id
    where enrol = 'elediamultikeys'
    ORDER BY c.shortname ASC";
$courses = $DB->get_records_sql($sql);
```

You would get no error.

If the output is not what you expect, please indicate why and the query may need to be revised.

Also I changed the above to use the JOIN clause rather than the WHERE clause for your join condition. That would not cause an error but is bad syntax.

Picture this, suppose you wanted the number of students enrolled in each course. You would use an aggregate function (count) on the students and the GROUP BY clause to group by course. It does not make sense, however, to GROUP BY course when you are not also counting the students, summing something else, or doing some sort of aggregation somewhere. GROUP BY only comes into play when you are aggregating (turning 2+ rows into 1 row).

Based on your edit, if the reason for the INSERT failing is that the USER column does not allow nulls (please provide all constraints on the table), you could try the following, which will skip the nulls --

```
// Get all courses which have an elediamultikeys enrol instance.
$sql = "SELECT c.*
    FROM {course} c
     join {enrol} e
       on e.courseid = c.id
    where enrol = 'elediamultikeys'
      and user is not null
    ORDER BY c.shortname ASC";
$courses = $DB->get_records_sql($sql);
```

Comment: Wow, awesome! That worked beautifully. I'll accept this answer as soon as they allow me to. Thank you. I also learned something today :)

Comment: @therhob no problem, so the output looks like what you need though? Sometimes people confuse group by w/ distinct, which is why I ask

Comment: I think so, but I may have just spoken to soon. Now that that is working it takes me to a page where I can input some information and generate unique license keys. Once I hit generate it blows up with the following, edited the original post...

Comment: @TheRhob what is the table structure of the table named "mdl_block_eledia_multikeys" It looks like the INSERT statement is failing, could be that a constraint is violated, or that there is a data type mismatch

Comment: The column names are id, course, code, [user], mailedto, timecreated, timeused..unfortunately my It department manages tables and won't allow manual table changes, hoping I can make another change in the plugin code... Line 151 shows the following, updated original post.

$DB->insert_record('block_eledia_multikeys', $newkeyobj);

Comment: @TheRhob does the query in my edit work? The only reason I can think that insert might fail is that the table is that the column USER has a not null constraint (and it's trying to insert a null which would violate that constraint). the query in my edit filters out nulls on that column in the select. Other possibilities are that a different constraint is violated or that there's a data type mismatch. The latter is less likely.

Comment: Hmmm...same error. Is there a way to use @Lmu92 's INSERT INTO idea with insert_record? It seems like there are two different areas that need changing, what you gave me before got me past the first error, but then it errors at the next part.

Comment: @TheRhob ah, did not notice that, are you able to try changing the file that has the insert statement? (from user to [user] )?

Comment: @TheRhob you could also select just those columns in the SELECT query (rather than all the columns, via c.*), then you would not need to specify the columns in the INSERT, and could just say "INSERT INTO mdl_block_eledia_multikeys values (x,y,z...)" and would not run into the problem w/ the reserved keyword. However you still have to change the insert, in either case

Comment: When I look at the code it doesn't actually say insert into though, it just says $DB->insert_record('block_eledia_multikeys', $newkeyobj);. can i just modify that line to insert into? I added the detailed code to my original post. What confuses me is the error says insert into, but that's not what is show in the code.

Comment: @TheRhob try changing line 5 of the code snippet you provided to: $newkeyobj->[user] = null;

Comment: @TheRhob you may be able to get away with just deleting that 5th line altogether; all it does is insert nulls, so if you're not inserting anything into it anyway, you should be able to leave it out. Assuming the same variable is not used elsewhere

Comment: Cool, it looks like that worked. I should be all set now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO mdl_block_eledia_multikeys (course,code,user,mailedto,timecreated)

will fail since user is a reserved keyword. Try brackets around the reserved word:

```
  INSERT INTO mdl_block_eledia_multikeys (course,code,[user],mailedto,timecreated) VALUES('2',N'4ajenabudE',NULL,N'email@gmail.com','1406479511')
```

Or even better: redesign the table and avoid using reserved keywords as column names.